# Request Permission issue related to Camera, Microphone, Photos & Contacts

Tags: objective-c, ios9

I am using objective c and I am facing problem with Request Permission  related to Camera, Microphone, Photos & Contacts in iOS 9.0.2.
In iOS 8.0 it is working fine but after upgrading the XCODE 7 then I am facing these permission issue. I searched a lot but not find any proper reason.
Please help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide some more details, what error message do you get?

Comment: these permission issue?